# Given small symmetric matrix A, calculate cofactor for large matrix B made using A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
a_2 & a_4 & a_5\\
a_3 & a_5 & a_6
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
how to calculate cofactor of matrix $$C=
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & B\\
B & A & B\\
B & B & A
\end{bmatrix}$$
size of $A$ is $N \times N$, $A$ is symmetric matrix,
matrix $A$ is repeated in matrix $C$,$K$ times only on diagonal of $C$.
E.g.,$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
3 & 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
if $k=2$ , then $$C =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & -1 & -1 \\
3 & 8 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 2 & 3\\
-1 & -1 & 3 & 8\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
how to calculate cofactor of $C_{11}$ 
I tried to solve this question using diagonal method of calculating determinants, i could find the repeating pattern but could not convert it into equation, please help me in converting into algebraic equation.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3317108) that was posted 7 hours ago? If you are the asker of these two questions, please delete one of them. Anyway, you can find the cofactors using [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317108/cofactor-of-special-laplacian-matrix by the same author.

Comment: sry i dont know about same question asked before, it is just coincidence, i will delete the question

Comment: @user1551 could you please explain a little bit more, i read the wiki but could not get proper insight of the question

Comment: @user8794581 Write your $C=\operatorname{diag}(A-B,A-B,A-B)-ee^T$ where $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T\in\mathbb R^9$. Then you may use Sherman-Morrison formula to find $C^{-1}$. Multiply it by $\det(C)$, you get $\operatorname{adj}(C)$. Taking transpose, you get the cofactor matrix.

Comment: how to calculate det(C) as C has large dimension

Comment: @user1551 i guess your solution will not work for large values of k.

Comment: @user8794581 $\det(C)$ is also calculated using rank-one update. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Answer (score 2):

This is a rank-one update of $\operatorname{diag}(A-B,\,\ldots,\,A-B)$. You can use [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) and the [determinant formula for rank-one update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to deal with it. With patience, you should get
$$
\operatorname{adj}(C)
=\det(Z)^{K-2}\pmatrix{
X+Y&Y&\cdots&Y\\
Y&X+Y&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&Y\\
Y&\cdots&Y&X+Y}
$$
when $K\ge2$, where
\begin{align}
Z&=A-B,\\
X&=\left(\det(Z)-Ke^T\operatorname{adj}(Z)e\right)\operatorname{adj}(Z),\\
Y&=\operatorname{adj}(Z)E\operatorname{adj}(Z)
\end{align}
with $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T\in\mathbb R^N$ being the all-one vector and $E=ee^T$ being the $N\times N$ all-one matrix. Now take the transpose of $\operatorname{adj}(C)$ to get the cofactor matrix.

Comment: so in my case if i want $C_{11}$, so my answer is det(z) ^(k-2) *( $X_{11}$ + $Y_{11}$), am i right

Comment: also, i want to ask why we need to take transpose, as it is symmetric

Comment: @user8794581 This answer works for any square matrix $A$. If your $A$ is symmetric, of course there is no need to take transpose to get the cofactors. And yes, $C_{11}=\det(Z)^{K-2}(X_{11}+Y_{11})$. By the way, $B=-E$.

Comment: how to modify this equation to get only $X_{11}$ and $Y_{11}$,as matrix may contain large elements,so i could work under modulo prime p.also which method can be used to find adj(Z) , i tried gaussian elimination but it requires numerical values,so any fast algorithm in O(n^4) which is independent of values and only requires computation on indices.

Comment: @user1551 I am not able to understand 'X' and 'Y' in your equation, can you tell me explictly how to calculate X11 + Y11?

Comment: @FirexFirexo Calculate $X$ and $Y$ first. Then add up their $(1,1)$-th entries.